# Can I get the Owning Object of a Member Function Template Parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, pointer-to-member, metatype

Given a object:

```
struct foo {
    void func();
};
```

Now given the templatized function declaration:

```
template<typename T, T F>
void bar();
```

So `bar` will be taking in a member function like so:

```
bar<decltype(&foo::func), &foo::func>()
```

In the body of `bar` I want to recover the type `foo` from `T`. Can I do that? I want to be able to do something like this:

```
get_obj<T> myfoo;

(myfoo.*F)();
```

I know that `get_obj` isn't a thing, but would there be a way to write it?

Comment: I figured I should mention that I do know that I can simplify `bar` to `template<auto F> void bar()` This just seemed simpler to write it this way.

Comment: "something like this" do you mean to do `myfoo.*F` instead of `foo.*F`?  And it appears you want to find the object type that a given member function is for, not the actual object?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes you're right. I'm failing at freehanding code today :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct get_memfun_class;
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct get_memfun_class<R(T::*)(Args...)> {
  using type=T;
};
template<class T>
using get_memfun_class_t=typename get_memfun_class<T>::type;


template<auto M>
using class_of_memfun = get_memfun_class_t< decltype(M) >;
```

`class_of_memfun<F>` is then the class of the memberfunction `F`.

To handle const/volatile/etc you end up having to do a bunch of versions.  This is annoying.  Here is an example of it:

```
template<class T>
struct get_memfun_class;
#define GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(...) \
template<class R, class T, class...Args> \
struct get_memfun_class<R(T::*)(Args...) __VA_ARGS__> { \
  using type=T; \
}
```

possibly you want:

```
template<class R, class T, class...Args> \
struct get_memfun_class<R(T::*)(Args...) __VA_ARGS__> { \
  using type=T __VA_ARGS__; \
}
```

is the type of the class of a pointer to a const memfun a const class or not?

Once you have chosen, you need to write 24 uses of the above macro:

```
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS();
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(volatile);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const volatile);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(volatile&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const volatile&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(&&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const&&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(volatile&&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const volatile&&);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(volatile noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const volatile noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(& noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const& noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(volatile& noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const volatile& noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(&& noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const&& noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(volatile&& noexcept);
GET_MEMFUN_CLASS(const volatile&& noexcept);
#undef GET_MEMFUN_CLASS

template<class T>
using get_memfun_class_t=typename get_memfun_class<T>::type;
```

I am unaware of a way to avoid doing all 24 of these specializations for full coverage.  If you think this is dumb, you are right; please feel free to express your annoyance by proposing a fix to the C++ standard committee.

If you are doing something like this for more than one trait, you can write the "strip lvalue, rvalue, noexcept and cv qualifiers" off part at one spot and pass them down in pieces.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3111e0f6fcfa02bb).

Comment: Ah, even the `*_t` nice touch. So in my example I could call this like: `get_memfun_class_t<T> myfoo`

Comment: OK just for my own understanding, I believe the second `get_memfun_class` is a specialization, right? Yet it takes more template arguments? I was trying to figure out how to do this by defaulting, but it looks like we can specify a different number of template arguments for a specialization?

Comment: @JonathanMee as I understood, the crucial point is `get_memfun_class<R(T::*)(Args...)>` on the specialization, so it actually still takes one parameter

Comment: But the `template<class R, class T, class... Args>` aren't those 3 arguments? I mean I guess they can't be because objects must be fully specified on declaration, and either way this only takes one argument. But if not arguments what are `R`, `T`, and `Args`? Maybe this should be made into a second question...

Comment: OK, I've tried to clarify this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52318110/2642059

Comment: this is a good solution, except for the fact that all that effort `class R, class T, class...Args` will fail when [an overloaded](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YcIkL1PGRmyD8zQr)  member function is available. That's not OP's case though.

Comment: @JeJo with overloads member function pointers are a bit tricky anyhow, thats not really a problem of this solution. Btw you can always pick the overload you want by casting it to a memfunpointer with the right signature

Comment: ah finally someone upvoted this but not mine. didnt feel right before

Comment: @JeJo Overloaded member functions are not objects and have no type.  ;)

Comment: Beware that this fails for `const`, `volatile` or `static` member functions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes; and I just added the really annoying boilerplate to fix that.  There is a bit of a question; is the class of a const member function a const type of the class?  What about r/lvalue qualified member functions?

Answer (score 7):

If you restrict to `void(T::mem_fun)()`:

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo {
    void func(){ std::cout << "foo"; }
};

template <typename T> struct get_type;
template <typename T> struct get_type<void(T::*)()> {
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T> using get_type_t = typename get_type<T>::type;


template<typename T, T F> void bar(){
    get_type_t<T> myfoo;
    (myfoo.*F)();
}

int main () {
    bar<decltype(&foo::func), &foo::func>();
}
```

Comment: Can we extend this with something like `template<typename T, typename R, typename Ts...> struct get_type<R(T::*)(Ts...)> { using type = T; };`

Comment: @JonathanMee I took the `(myfoo.*F)();`  as given. With arbitrary return and params i guess it is possible just a bit more complicated ;)

Comment: Beware that this fails for `const`, `volatile` or `static` member functions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `static` is kinda ovious, the other cases arent that clear to me, will have to do some research. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @user463035818 You can fix the cv problem by adding specializations like `template <typename T> struct get_type<void(T::*)() const>`, etc. There may be a clever solution with a `std::remove_cv_t` but I don't see it.