# When specializing a class, how can I take a different number of template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I just asked this question: [Can I get the Owning Object of a Member Function Template Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52317134/2642059) and [Yakk - Adam Nevraumont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk-adam-nevraumont)'s answer had the code:

```
template<class T>
struct get_memfun_class;

template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct get_memfun_class<R(T::*)(Args...)> {
    using type=T;
};
```

These is clearly an initial declaration and then a specialization of `struct get_memfun_class`. But I find myself uncertain: **Can specializations have a different number of template parameters?**

For example, is something like this legal?

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T&);

template<typename K, typename V>
void foo<pair<K, V>>(const pair<K, V>&);
```

Are there no requirements that specializations must take the same number of parameters?

Comment: "These are clearly 2 specializations of ..." Er, there's only one specialization.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by different number of template parameters? The example does have a different number of template parameters (`R`, `T`, and `Args`) than the primary (`T`). Also, the `foo` example isn't legal because you can't partially specialize function templates.

Comment: @Barry Isn't the second one legal as it is an overload, not a partial specialization?

Comment: @NathanOliver It's legal as an overload, yes, but it's written as a partial specialization.

Comment: Ah, yep, missed that part.

Comment: @Barry I'm just trying to understand how specializations can take a differing number of template arguments. Does that make sense?

Comment: You cannot partially specialize functions, contrary to classes.

Comment: @JonathanMee Like, are you asking why `get_memfun_class` works as written?

Comment: @Barry I was asking how were a different number of template parameters allowed in the specialization. From the answers given, it seems that the reason is that this is allowed, and the arguments can even be deduced as part of *partial* template specialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to confuse the template parameters of the explicit specialization and the template arguments you use to specialize the template.

```
template<class T> // one argument
struct get_memfun_class; // get_memfun_class takes one template (type) argument

template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct get_memfun_class<R(T::*)(Args...)> {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                      one type argument
    using type=T;
}; // explicit specialization takes one template argument
```

Yes, there are three template parameters for the explicit specialization, but that doesn't mean that the explicit specialization takes three arguments. They are there to be deduced. You can form a single type using multiple type parameters, which is what is happening there. Also consider that you can fully specialize a template:

```
template <>
struct get_memfun_class<void>;
//                      ^^^^
//                    one type argument
```

Here it's the same thing. Yes, the explicit specialization takes no parameters, but that just means that there is none to be deduced and indeed you are explicitly writing a template parameter (`void`) and so the amount of template arguments of the specialization match those of the primary template.

Your example is invalid because you cannot partially specialize functions.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there no requirements that specializations must take the same number of parameters?

There is; and is satisfied in your example.

When you write

```
template<class T>
struct get_memfun_class;
```

you say that `get_mumfun_class` is a template `struct` with a single template `typename` argument; and when you write

```
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct get_memfun_class<R(T::*)(Args...)> {
    using type=T;
};
```

you define a specialization that receive a single template typename argument in the form `R(T::*)(Args...)`.

From the single type `R(T::*)(Args...)`, you can deduce more that one template paramenters (`R`, `T` and the variadic `Args...`, in this example) but the type `R(T::*)(Args...)` (a method of a class that receive a variadic list of arguments) remain one.

> For example, is something like this legal?

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T&);

template<typename K, typename V>
void foo<pair<K, V>>(const pair<K, V>&);
```

No, but (as written in comments) the second one isn't a class/struct partial specialization (where `std::pair<K, V>` remain a single type), that is legal; it's a template **function** partial specialization that is forbidden.

But you can **full** specialize a template function; so it's legal (by example)

```
 template<>
 void foo<std::pair<long, std::string>(const std::pair<long, std::string>&);
```

as is legal the full specialization for `get_memfun_class` (to make another example)

```
template<>
struct get_memfun_class<std::pair<long, std::string>> {
    using type=long long;
};
```

Comment: the first senctence ("Yes;...") seems to contradict what you write later: "a specialization that receive a single template typename arguement"

Comment: @user463035818 - you're right: "yes" as a response to a question that start whit "are there no" isn't a good idea; thanks. Modified with "There is".