# How to remove decltype(&MyClass::funct) part by extending the following type traits?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, pointer-to-member

I wanted to have type traits which will help me to get the type of the class
from a member function pointer. I looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317134)
and found my half way to the aim.

It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// example class
struct MyClass {
    void funct() { std::cout << "funct has been called....\n"; }
};

// traits
template<typename Class> struct get_class{};
template<typename ReType, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct get_class<ReType(Class::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = Class;
};
template<typename Type> using get_class_t = typename get_class<Type>::type;

int main()
{
    get_class_t<decltype(&MyClass::funct)> myObj;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ---> this is a lot of typing
    myObj.funct();
    return 0;
}
```

But, as shown in the code I need every time to write `get_class_t<decltype(&MyClass::funct)>`
or in the case of

```
  auto ptr =  &MyClass::funct;
  get_class_t<decltype(ptr)> myObj;
  //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is a lot of `decltype()`ing. I would like to write instead

```
class_t<ptr> obj;
or
class_t<&MyClass::funct> myObj;
```

which is more convenient.

I did the following function, which will return a resulting object of the class
and maybe I could do, want I wanted to.

```
template<typename Type>
auto helper_function(Type ptr)->get_class_t<Type>
{
    return get_class_t<Type>{};
}

template<typename Type>
using class_t = /* decltype(helper_function(Type ptr));*/ 
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // what could be here?
```

I do not know how to complete this. My goal is to extend the traits in such a way that I
could create an object like

```
auto ptr = &MyClass::funct;
class_t<ptr> myObj;
// or
class_t<&MyClass::funct> myObj;
```

Is there any other way to do this? or should I have to stick with `decltype()`ing?

**As I have tagged, I would like to see whether it possible with C++11?**

Comment: As I tagged I would like to see whether it possible with **C++11**?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude IMO if one tags the specific version of the standard that person want's an answer for that standard. I think it's always crucial

Comment: @Timo, the OP and others: Many beginners and newbies (and sometime intermediate knowledge posters) very often put specific standard-version tags in their question, when their questions could be about generic C++. It's impossible without explicit mentioning to know if it's deliberate or by mistake.

Comment: No, this is not really possible in C++11.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then err on the side of caution by asking first if you're not sure!!

Comment: Out of curiosity... what is the use case you envision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can provide a function which will create required object. This is very simple to achieve:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
auto makeObjectForMethod(T&&, Args&& ...args) -> get_class_t<decltype(&MyClass::funct)>
{
    using R = get_class_t<decltype(&MyClass::funct)>;
    return R{ std::forward(args)... };
}

int main()
{
    auto myObj = makeObjectForMethod(&MyClass::funct);

    myObj.funct();
    return 0;
}
```

Works with C++11 and is quite handy:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/usMa3fA0I2HCNJ7M

The only disadvantage that in case of class fields it is not very helpful.

Comment: A good solution iff there are no ctor args. Not a general solution but I suppose that may not matter here.

Comment: current version works with ctor args, which can be passed as extra arguments of `makeObjectForMethod`.

Comment: Better! Still not sure I'd use this in reality but it's a valid workaround to not being able to get just the type. Just be careful of potential copies on return if the thingie isn't moveable (and RVO doesn't kick in) cos this is pre-C++17

Comment: I realize there is no way out for C++11 compiler but this could make it better, but not the best.

Answer (score 11):

*(Answer archived for future visitors; this solution requires C++17!)*

---

You're really close!

The trick is `auto` template arguments, and the fact that pointers-to-members can be used as template arguments, like so:

```
template <auto thing>
using class_t = get_class_t<decltype(thing)>;

int main()
{
    class_t<&MyClass::funct> myObj;
    myObj.funct();
}
```

Of course if you can write this then you already know the type so you'd just write `MyClass`, so that's not very useful.

Sadly you won't be able to make it accept `ptr` as a template argument, though; you're stuck with `get_class_t` for that:

```
int main()
{
    auto ptr = &MyClass::funct;
    get_class_t<decltype(ptr)> myObj;
    myObj.funct();
}
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71ed0a4613c95cac))

In the latter case, a nice type alias can help you a bit:

```
auto ptr = &MyClass::funct;

using ClassType = get_class_t<decltype(ptr)>;
ClassType myObj;

myObj.funct();
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9327b875d4f8e9b0))

Personally I think this level of verbosity is pretty reasonable.

Comment: I have already so that in the linked post. But `auto things` need C++17. As I tagged I would like to see whether it possible with **C++11**. https://godbolt.org/z/3v3SVh

Comment: @UsingCpp Dang, someone removed that tag. Sorry. I'll keep this answer up for posterity but I think you're out of luck then.